# how to convert multiple column data in single row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of ***PostalCode***, now i want to move all data in single row like give second table

```
PostalId    Country  StateId    DistrictId
--------    -------  -------    ----------
  110051          1      110         10165
```

Second Table

```
RowNo  Value
-----  -----
1      110051   
2      1  
3      110  
4      10165
```

Comment: `select RowNo, PostalId from 
(select 1 as RowNo,PostalId as Value from PostalCode
union all
select 2,Country from PostalCode
union all
select 3,StateId from PostalCode
union all
select 4,DistrictId from PostalCode);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with

```
SELECT V.RowNo,
       V.Value
FROM   PostalCode
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, PostalId),
                           (2, Country),
                           (3, StateId),
                           (4, DistrictId) )V(RowNo, Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try other one way to achieve the above result using `CROSS APPLY` with `XML` Method :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                        (
                            SELECT NULL
                        )) RowNo,
       split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') Value
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), PostalId)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Country)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), StateId)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DistrictId), ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM PostalCode
) AS Z
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
RowNo  Value
-----  -----
1      110051   
2      1  
3      110  
4      10165
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowNo) RowNo, Value 
    FROM PostalCode UNPIVOT( Value FOR 
                      RowNo IN ([PostalId], [Country], [StateId], [DistrictId] ) ) UNPVT
```

Comment: This returns the results with `RowNo` assigned in alphabetical order (`Country, DistrictId, PostalId, StateId`) - not the order stated (`PostalId,Country,StateId,DistrictId  `)